# Consuming SOAP web services with cookie-based authentication from Oracle stored procedure with PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, web-services, cookies, soap, plsql

We are trying to consume a secure (https) web service with PL/SQL directly from Oracle DB stored procedures. There is a seperate web service for user actions (login/logout) and its documentation states

> Upon successful login a session cookie is created. Web service client must be configured to receive cookies. After logging in subsequent calls will succeed as long as they include the session cookie which is received by login.

However we do not know how to store and use that cookie from PL/SQL. Any help will be appriciated..

---

NOTES:

- We have successfuly created the Oracle Wallet, add the web servies' certificates to the wallet and assigned it to the request as follows:

  ```
  Declare
    ...
    v_req_context    UTL_HTTP.REQUEST_CONTEXT_KEY;
    ...
  Begin
    ...
    v_req_context := UTL_HTTP.CREATE_REQUEST_CONTEXT(wallet_path => 'file:'||ssl_cert_wallet_path,
                                                     wallet_password => ssl_cert_wallet_password);
    v_http_request := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(url             => 'https://<url_to_webservice_wsdl>',
                                             method          => 'POST',
                                             http_version    => 'HTTP/1.1',
                                             request_context => v_req_context);
    ...
  End;
  ```
- We are making a request to the user service as follows:

  ```
  Begin
    -- SOAP Authentication request parameters
    v_string_request := '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:examples:userService">
                           <soapenv:Header/>
                           <soapenv:Body>
                             <urn:' || v_service_operation || ' soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:urn="' || v_service_namespace || '/">
                               <userId>' || p_username || '</userId>
                               <password>' || p_password || '</password>
                               <lang>' || p_lang || '</lang>
                             </urn:' || v_service_operation || '>
                           </soapenv:Body>
                         </soapenv:Envelope>';

    UTL_HTTP.SET_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT(60);

    v_http_request := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(url             => v_host_name || ':' || v_port || v_service_posfix,
                                             method          => 'POST',
                                             http_version    => 'HTTP/1.1',
                                             request_context => v_req_context);

    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(v_http_request, 'Host', v_host_name || ':' || v_port);
    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(v_http_request, 'Connection', 'close');
    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(v_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(v_http_request, 'SOAPAction', '"' || v_service_operation || '"');
    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(v_http_request, 'Content-Length', length(v_string_request));

    <<login_request_loop>>
    for i in 0..CEIL(LENGTH(v_string_request) / v_buffer_size) - 1
    loop
      v_substring_msg := SUBSTR(v_string_request, i * v_buffer_size + 1, v_buffer_size);

      begin
        v_raw_data := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(c => v_substring_msg);
        UTL_HTTP.WRITE_RAW(r => v_http_request, data => v_raw_data);
      exception
        when NO_DATA_FOUND then EXIT login_request_loop;
      end;
    end loop login_request_loop;

    -- SOAP Authentication request
    v_http_response := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(v_http_request);
    ...
  End;
  ```

Comment: Are you sure you need to process cookies manually? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_http.htm#i1012714 says cookies are automatically managed by UTL_HTTP as long as subsequent calls are in the same database session. If you actually need cookie manipulation, the same document should give you a start.

Comment: We have tried to consume the main actions after calling the login function but no way, did not work as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me drop the answer for future use:

If the web service you are trying to consume is a secure (https) web service, then do not set the `Host` seperately in header.
The code works like charm if you remove the line:

```
UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(v_http_request, 'Host', v_host_name || ':' || v_port);
```

PS: I have discovered that all by myself, so I could not refer to any sources.